# How to disable logging of ChromeDriver using Selenium and JavaFX

Tags: java, selenium, logging, javafx, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my app java is always writing things like:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5) on port 19943
Only local connections are allowed.
сен 27, 2018 11:18:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

How can I prevent it? I don't need it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These logs you mentioned are the default *ChromeDriver* **startup logs**. As the **log level** is not configured until a session is created you don't have any control over the generation of these logs.

Moving forward, during *Test Execution* to see *lesser logs* you can simply pass **--silent** argument to the *chromedriver server* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class A_Chrome_General
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentLogging", "true");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
            System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Block output generated by Selenium Python that contains cookiebanner.js information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196641/block-output-generated-by-selenium-python-that-contains-cookiebanner-js-informat/66200689#66200689)

Comment: how can I achieve this for IE, Edge, Opera and Firefox?